# can't open PORT on IPTABLES firewall

Tags: linux, port, firewall, iptables

I'm struggling to understand why I can't open port 61616 by adding IPTABLES rule. Here is the listing of all rules, obtained via IPTABLES -L command.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:61616
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:cslistener
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:cslistener
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:webcache
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:61616
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp any
ACCEPT     esp  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     ah   --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251         udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

As much as I'm ignorant about IPTABLES, what confuses me is that http port is visible from the outside, yet port 61616 still isn't. For me, the rules look the same. Anyways, all help's appreciated.

Best

Comment: the above seems OK, the port should be open. How are you testing ? Are you sure it's a TCP port not a UDP one ?

Comment: Using `iptables -L -v` will show you which rules are being matched. Is there a service running on that port? Might there be another firewall between your testing system and your server?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try to open port for host in the network behind the CentOS host (CentOS host is firewall for network)?
If so, you must add rule for chain FORWARD of table filter, and you should 
add rule for DNAT to some IP in network x.x.x.x

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 61616 -j  ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 61616 -j DNAT --to-destinanion x.x.x.x
```